# How to turn a LaTeX3 package key fontsize value into a command?

Tags: l3keys

I do not know how to search for this issue as `backwards slash` or `\` in questions has not gleaned anything useful. How can I set a key-value and then use a font size value without having to use a command in the package options please, e.g.

```latex
\usepackage[superscript-fontsize=large]{aminosymb}
```

instead of

```latex
\usepackage[superscript-fontsize=\large]{aminosymb}
```

I would prefer for the package I am writing to not have to put the backwards slash in the package options although this is always a backup. For instance, my MWE produces this:

[image]

using this command:

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \aasp } { m m }
  {
    \residueString:nn { #1 } { \l_aminosymb_residue_style_tl }
    \textsuperscript{$\l_superscript_font_size_tl\mkern-1mu#2\mkern-1.5mu$}
  }
```

I do not know if there is a LaTeX3 command to convert tokens into a command, does anyone know how this can be done please? MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{aminosymb.sty}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {aminosymb}
  {today}
  {version}
  {Typesetting amino acid residues with notation and numbers}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_aminosymb_residue_style_tl
\tl_new:N \l_superscript_font_size_tl

\keys_define:nn { AminoSymb / Package }
  {
    style .tl_set:N  = \l_aminosymb_residue_style_tl,
    style .initial:n = abbrev-firstcap,
    superscript-fontsize .tl_set:N = \l_superscript_font_size_tl,
    superscript-fontsize .initial:n = scriptstyle,
  }

\ProcessKeysOptions { AminoSymb / Package }

\prop_new:N \l_abbrev_ala_prop
\prop_new:N \l_abbrev_all_prop

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_abbrev_ala_prop
  {
    initial-lower=a,
    abbrev-firstcap = Ala,
  }

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_abbrev_all_prop
  {
    ala = \l_abbrev_ala_prop,
  }

\cs_new:Npn \residueString:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_set:Nx\l_residue{#1}
    \tl_set:Nx\l_style{#2}
    \prop_map_function:NN \l_abbrev_all_prop \__abbrev_aux:nn
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn\prop_item:Nn{Ne}

\cs_new:Npn \__abbrev_aux:nn #1#2
     {
        \prop_map_inline:Nn #2
        {
          \tl_if_eq:NnT
          \l_residue
          {##2}
          {\prop_item:Ne#2{\l_style}}
        }
      }

\NewDocumentCommand { \aasp } { m m }
  {
    \residueString:nn { #1 } { \l_aminosymb_residue_style_tl }
    \textsuperscript{$\l_superscript_font_size_tl\mkern-1mu#2\mkern-1.5mu$}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[superscript-fontsize=large]{aminosymb}

\begin{document}

\aasp{a}{323}

\end{document}
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I do not know how to search for this issue due to the nature of the `\` command.

Comment: Consider not using package options at all, but instead a `setup`-macro that can be used after the package is loaded.

Comment: Please note that you're violating the naming conventions of `expl3`. See my edited answer for a version that fixes it. All your functions should contain the module name, same is true for all your variables.

Comment: @Skillmon I appreciate the feedback, LaTeX3 is some learning curve but will be worth it, thanks for the help! Will fix it in my main document now

Comment: In summary, a variable should be called `\<scope>_<module>_<description>_<type>` or if it's private `\<scope>__<module>_<description>_<type>`. And a function should always be called `\<module>_<description>:<args>` or if it's private `\__<module>_<description>:<args>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\cs_if_exist_use:c`, if you want to throw an error if it's not available you can as well use `\cs_if_exist_use:cF`.

The following silently ignores an unknown command. Also I fixed the way you set the font command (has to be used outside of the maths context). And I also put `\exp_stop_f:` after your `\mkern` so that they don't affect `#2`.

Additionally I removed the hard dependency on `l3keys2e`, as you can use the built-in `\ProcessKeyOptions` in recent kernels, and only need `l3keys2e` for older LaTeX versions.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{aminosymb.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {aminosymb}
  {today}
  {version}
  {Typesetting amino acid residues with notation and numbers}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_aminosymb_residue_style_tl
\tl_new:N \l_aminosymb_superscript_font_size_tl

\keys_define:nn { AminoSymb / Package }
  {
    style .tl_set:N  = \l_aminosymb_residue_style_tl,
    style .initial:n = abbrev-firstcap,
    superscript-fontsize .tl_set:N = \l_aminosymb_superscript_font_size_tl,
    superscript-fontsize .initial:n = scriptstyle,
  }

\cs_if_exist:NTF \ProcessKeyOptions
  {
    \ProcessKeyOptions [ AminoSymb / Package ]
  }
  {
    \RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
    \ProcessKeysOptions { AminoSymb / Package }
  }

\prop_new:N \l_aminosymb_abbrev_ala_prop
\prop_new:N \l_aminosymb_abbrev_all_prop

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_aminosymb_abbrev_ala_prop
  {
    initial-lower=a,
    abbrev-firstcap = Ala,
  }

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_aminosymb_abbrev_all_prop
  {
    ala = \l_aminosymb_abbrev_ala_prop,
  }

\cs_new:Npn \aminosymb_residueString:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_set:Nx\l_aminosymb_residue_tl{#1}
    \tl_set:Nx\l_aminosymb_style_tl{#2}
    \prop_map_function:NN \l_aminosymb_abbrev_all_prop \__aminosymb_abbrev_aux:nn
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn\prop_item:Nn{Ne}

\cs_new:Npn \__aminosymb_abbrev_aux:nn #1#2
     {
        \prop_map_inline:Nn #2
        {
          \tl_if_eq:NnT
          \l_aminosymb_residue_tl
          {##2}
          {\prop_item:Ne#2{\l_aminosymb_style_tl}}
        }
      }

\NewDocumentCommand { \aasp } { m m }
  {
    \aminosymb_residueString:nn { #1 } { \l_aminosymb_residue_style_tl }
    \textsuperscript
      {
        \cs_if_exist_use:c { \l_aminosymb_superscript_font_size_tl }
        $ \mkern-1mu\exp_stop_f: #2 \mkern-1.5mu\exp_stop_f: $
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[superscript-fontsize=large]{aminosymb}

\begin{document}

\aasp{a}{323}

\end{document}
```