# LaTeX3 package option .initial:N is not being respected and used in a command

Tags: key-value

I asked a question earlier that was [helpfully answered by Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698208/273733) but have ran into an issue when relying on the `.initial:N` value of a package option e.g.

```
\usepackage[superscript-fontsize=large]{aminosymb}
```

compiles whereas

```
\usepackage{aminosymb}
```

doesn't and fails with

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9 \noindent\aasp{h}{22}
```

What is causing this issue, I assumed that setting the `.initial` value of a package option would be respected, where have I went wrong please?

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{aminosymb.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {aminosymb}
  {today}
  {version}
  {Typesetting amino acid residues with notation and numbers}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_aminosymb_residue_style_tl
\tl_new:N \l_superscript_font_size_tl

\keys_define:nn { AminoSymb / Package }
  {
    style .tl_set:N  = \l_aminosymb_residue_style_tl,
    style .initial:n = abbrev-firstcap,
    superscript-fontsize .tl_set:N = \l_superscript_font_size_tl,
    superscript-fontsize .initial:n = scriptstyle,
  }

\cs_if_exist:NTF \ProcessKeyOptions
  {
    \ProcessKeyOptions [ AminoSymb / Package ]
  }
  {
    \RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
    \ProcessKeysOptions { AminoSymb / Package }
  }

\prop_new:N \l_aminosymb_abbrev_ala_prop
\prop_new:N \l_aminosymb_abbrev_all_prop

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_aminosymb_abbrev_ala_prop
  {
    initial-lower=a,
    abbrev-firstcap = Ala,
  }

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_aminosymb_abbrev_all_prop
  {
    ala = \l_aminosymb_abbrev_ala_prop,
  }

\cs_new:Npn \aminosymb_residueString:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_set:Nx\l_aminosymb_residue_tl{#1}
    \tl_set:Nx\l_aminosymb_style_tl{#2}
    \prop_map_function:NN \l_aminosymb_abbrev_all_prop \__aminosymb_abbrev_aux:nn
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn\prop_item:Nn{Ne}

\cs_new:Npn \__aminosymb_abbrev_aux:nn #1#2
     {
        \prop_map_inline:Nn #2
        {
          \tl_if_eq:NnT
          \l_aminosymb_residue_tl
          {##2}
          {\prop_item:Ne#2{\l_aminosymb_style_tl}}
        }
      }

\NewDocumentCommand { \aasp } { m m }
  {
    \aminosymb_residueString:nn { #1 } { \l_aminosymb_residue_style_tl }
    \textsuperscript
      {
        \cs_if_exist_use:c { \l_superscript_font_size_tl }
        $ \mkern-1mu\exp_stop_f: #2 \mkern-1.5mu\exp_stop_f: $
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{aminosymb} % <--- doesn't work
%\usepackage[superscript-fontsize=large]{aminosymb} % <--- works

\begin{document}

\aasp{a}{323}

\end{document}
```

Note: I have made more changes to the naming conventions in my main `.sty` file (`\l_aminosymb_superscriptfontsize_tl` etc) and further edits but the code above is the code as answered in the linked question, I think it is probably too substantial for a comment on that answer and perhaps could help others by being its own question (hopefully!).

Comment: unrelated to that, you don't need to use `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` in an Expl Package.

Comment: @UdiFogiel thank you, will remove it now, this is my first attempt at an Expl package so anything that can help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue here because your last example (meaning in the old question) didn't use a maths-style command, but a font-size command.

The latter only affects your maths-material if used *outside* the inline maths. The former however has to be used *inside* your inline maths.

So if you want to only use `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, or `\scriptscriptstyle` you have to move the `\cs_if_exist_use:c { \l_aminosymb_superscript_font_size_tl }` (note that I changed the variable name, yours in this MWE is missing the module name -- which I also missed in my older answer) after the opening `$`.

But if you want to use `\large` and friends, you have to move it in front of the opening `$`.

If you want to have both, you'll need to either put in additional parsing effort (branching in the two cases), or provide an additional key.

The error isn't that `.initial:n` is not obeyed (which you can see by using `\tl_show:N \l_aminosymb_superscript_font_size_tl` after your `\keys_define:nn` block).

Comment: Skillmon I can't believe that, I meant to write `scriptsize` not `scriptstyle` in my `.initial` value, thank you for pointing that out, just twigged reading your answer, sorry for the issue

Comment: @JamesT don't worry, it happens to all of us :)